# Javascript - Sort array by date and alphabetically in the same time

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date, alphabetical

I have an array with objects that contain titles and dates.

```
[{
   title: 'Some title'
   date: '12.00 PM 17/10/2014'
},
...
]
```

**I need to sort that values by date and alphabetically in the same time, the result should look like follows:**

```
1.00 PM - Btitle
1.00 PM - Bztitle
1.00 PM - Ctitle
3.00 PM - Atitle
3.00 PM - Btitle
```

Should I create additional arrays to remember state etc? Or maybe it's possible to do within single `sort` method.

Comment: do you have access to moment.js?

Comment: Tip: If you could get a `string` out of the `date/time` in the format `YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss` and concatenate it with the `title`, you then could sort the `array` by this _merged_ data.

Comment: Discussed at [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason?cb=1) right now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it in a single `sort` method. The bones of it are:

```
yourArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    var adate = /* ...parse the date in a.date... */,
        bdate = /* ...parse the date in b.date... */,
        rv = adate - bdate;
    if (rv === 0) {
        rv = a.title.localeCompare(b.title);
    }
    return rv;
});
```

I'll leave the parsing of that odd date format as an exercise for the reader...